# GitKraken Pro not working on Student Account

Tags: gitkraken

I'm a student and I have the student developer pack on Github (also indicated by a "pro" tag). I use Gitkraken for work and I need GitKraken Pro to manage multiple private repos. I know that GitKraken gives Pro accounts to students but it seems like mine is not working. I've tried going to **Preferences**-> **Authentication** ->**GitHub** and generated an SSH Key. I've also tried logging off and logging back in. Any ideas why my account isn't registering as a pro account? Thanks!

Comment: GitKraken is not a product from GitHub but from Axosoft.

Comment: You're right. GitKraken offers pro accounts to students (indicated by the pro tag on GitHub)

Comment: But do you have the "[student developer pack](https://help.github.com/en/github/teaching-and-learning-with-github-education/applying-for-a-student-developer-pack)" on github?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for pointing that out. I'll make sure to include that

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are already signed in GitHub for working with repositories, you need to sign out of your current GitKraken Account and sign in there with your GitHub as a new GitKraken Account.

File -> Sign into different account -> Sign in with GitHub

Comment: This still does not work, unfortunately. :(